# Azure roles in emulator keep picking up changes?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, sdk, emulation

my Web and worker roles in my emulator keep detecting changes to my config and recycling.. sometimes one a minute.. here is an example output that they give

---

```
Diagnostics]: Checking for configuration updates 6/22/2013 7:39:11 AM.
[Diagnostics]: New config request downloaded. Applying changes...
[Diagnostics]: Signalling process restart on event = WADDM-ShutDown-170706a9530e43d2bc68efd1e5d9be43
[MonAgentHost] Output: Exiting the monitoring agent 10232 after the shutdown event was signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Stopped
[Diagnostics] Information: Diagnostic process exited with code: 0
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\35cb660c-05d0-4367-bde0-a58a84fe34cf\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Projects\Catapult\Microsoft-JLA\ScaleOutData\ScaleOutData.Azure\csx\Release\roles\ScaleOutData.Azure.WebConsole\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\35cb660c-05d0-4367-bde0-a58a84fe34cf\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile "C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\35cb660c-05d0-4367-bde0-a58a84fe34cf\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\35cb660c-05d0-4367-bde0-a58a84fe34cf\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-74148cc47dc349fb95512518a2a49560 -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-74148cc47dc349fb95512518a2a49560 -parent 12144 -events
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-74148cc47dc349fb95512518a2a49560 is signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-74148cc47dc349fb95512518a2a49560 after the agent is initialized.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 12144 exits.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
[Diagnostics]: Applied new configuration.
[Diagnostics]: Configuration poll finished.
```

---

They also throw ALOT (like one every 10 seconds) of this message

---

```
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-06-22T12:40:56.074Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     20540
[MonAgentHost] Error:     21200
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     8b7acfe3-ddf4-4370-8c1e-6352fd1
[MonAgentHost] Error:     netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f94
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
```

---

I am all ears as to what could be causing all this chattiness and recycling.

Answer (score 1):

NM: Un install of EVERYTHING and reinstall fixed this.. now to figure out why the cache times out when storing one object in the emulator.. it worked for about a week... now totally broken!